# clojure classpath problem for (require) function?

Tags: java, clojure, classpath

CLASSPATH has the "/Users/smcho/Desktop/clojure" as one of its path, and this directory has the file hello.clj.

Running clojure, and running (require 'hello) give this error message.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate hello__init.class or hello.clj on classpath:  (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

When I change directory to "/Users/.../clojure", and run the same (require 'hello), there's no problem. The . is on the CLASSPATH.

Running

```
java -cp /Users/smcho/bin/jar/clojure.jar:/Users/smcho/Desktop/clojure clojure.lang.Repl
```

also works.

Why clojure can't find the source on the CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like Alex mentioned, if you start java with the -cp argument, then the CLASSPATH environment is not referenced. So, instead of

```
java -cp /Users/smcho/bin/jar/clojure.jar clojure.lang.Repl
```

use

```
java -cp /Users/smcho/bin/jar/clojure.jar:$CLASSPATH clojure.lang.Repl
```

You can examine your java classpath from within the Clojure repl:

```
(doseq [p (.getURLs (java.lang.ClassLoader/getSystemClassLoader))] (println (.getPath p)))
```

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify what commandline you used for the first example, but note that if you use the `-cp` flag, the CLASSPATH environment variable is not referenced.